# java anoymous class can access private member of outer class. Why this code cannot access private data member?

Tags: java

I want to access private member of a class by anonymous class created in a different class.
I am new to java, kindly please explain this and tell what i am doing wrong.

```
class movie{
    private String moviename="bahubali";
    void display(){
        System.out.println(moviename);
   }
}

public class InnerClass{ //main class

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        movie anonymous=new movie() {
            void display() {
                System.out.println(moviename+" in anonymous class");
            }
        };
    
        anonymous.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: movie is not an outer class. It's rather a separate class altogether.

Comment: anonymous class or inner class?

Comment: @RinkalRohara so can you tell where this anonymous class is created by the compiler? is it in Main class or in the movie class?

Comment: @VeKe anonymous is also a inner class of non static type

Answer (score 2):

Your anonymous class inherits from the class `movie` (you should make it `Movie` instead btw. to comply with Java standards).

Inheriting classes are granted access to `protected` members, not to `private` members.

So the fix in this case should be changing

```
private String moviename="bahubali";
```

to

```
protected String moviename="bahubali";
```

.

Comment: i m just practicing concepts so forget about java naming standards. i was just checking that anonymous can access private members of the outer class, so i just figured out that we can do this in enclosing class(in my case -can access the private member of main class which is InnerClass).